# Java - Different socket for same TCP IP

Tags: java, thread-safety, socket.io

I want to create different thread for read and write method by using socket.
I wonder should I use different socket or same socket to share for both thread?

Comment: what i do is open 1 socket. only 1 thread listens and i also add a "send" method that is synchronized and any thread can use it

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading and writing to and from the same device/object, i'd use the same thread. This way you don't have it trying to read something when you haven't written to it yet. Doing multiple threads might cause a multitude of errors if you're not careful, such as nulls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same socket to both read and write. Of course one of the 2 endpoints must open a server socket. Then you can have 1 thread blocked waiting for input data while another thread could output data when needed

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Create **One socket object**.

**2.** Use any nos of threads to access this object, but **do keep enough care to make the 
       write and read operations** `Thread-Safe`.

**3.** Try using the `ServerChannel` and `ServerSocketChannel` from `java.util.nio` package, which is **Asynchronous** .

Comment: NIO is not asynchronous. It can be non-blocking. Not the same thing.